# When should $and operator be skipped in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/mongodb-exercise-12.php

```
db.restaurants.find(
                           {
                             "cuisine" : {$ne : "American "},
                             "grades.score" :{$gt: 70},
                             "address.coord" : {$lt : -65.754168}
                            }
                     );
```

Following is mentioned there

```
Note : Do this query without using $and operator.
```

If it can be solved without $and operator, then is $and operator just for readability sake or there is any particular reason we should prefer to use $and operator?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html). Sometimes `$and` is required, sometimes it can be omitted.

Comment: @str Thank you for pointing out the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $and operator just for readability sake

No,

> When should $and operator should be skipped in MongoDB?

`other than below cases`

1. Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the `Same Field`, then only option to achieve is using `and`
2. Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the `Same Operator`

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator)

If you have to perform `A OR (B AND C)`, then you need to use `$or`, `$and`.

If you have to get all `American cushiness` or `abc cushiness` with `grades score` or `address coord`, you need to use `$and, $or`

And the link OP mentioned is an exercise, so you can achieve that with/without `$and`.